# ZendGuardLoader seg faulting with apache

Tags: php, apache2, zend-guard

I am getting a seg fault whenever I try to access php files in the web root that were encoded with Zend Guard. My ZendGuard that I used to encode that files is set to php5 and my php version I am running on apache is 5.5.9. I have added the following to /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/ZendGuardLoader.so
zend_loader.enable=1
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
```

My phpinfo page shows this 
[image]

This is what shows up in my /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Tue Oct 11 11:01:11.147536 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5356] AH00051: child pid 5359 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my issue, apparently OpCache was the one that was crashing so I took the zend_extension for opcache out of the php.ini

**Remove These From php.ini:**

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
```